# Safety of not catching SQL Exception

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, exception, sqlexception

Let's say I have a program that puts email addresses into a database where the email attribute is a primary key.
If I have a duplicate email address, I could deal with it in two ways.

1) run a "select email from table" query. If the email is currently in there, don't add it. 
2) don't check if email is in the table. catch(SQLException e), but don't print the stack trace, simply skip over it. This way, if I'm inserting a duplicate it effectively ignores it.

Granted with method 1, I'm only executing a simple select query (no joins or anything fancy) so performance isn't really a huge issue. But if I wanted to optimize performance, would method 2 be a viable, safe way of doing this?
So instead of running a "select ..." every time, I just add it.

Are there any safety issues with skipping over the exception?

Java Example (with JDBC):

```
try {
    String sql = "insert into emails values(?)";
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pstmt.setString(1, email);
    pstmt.execute();
    return true;
}

catch(SQLException e) {
    // e.printStackTrace(); // skip; don't print out error
    return false;
}
```

Comment: In mysql you can do `INSERT IGNORE` which won't insert row if it violates unique constraint .

Comment: If you are concerned that much about performance, I'd say you should stop using an email address as the primary key in the first place.  Having an email address as primary key in my opinion is absurd.